# How to track Top Left position of rectangle when scaling from center of pages.

Tags: rectangles

I am building some drawing apps that require to track the XY coordinate of user drawing rectangle (it can be multiple rectangle) on image. Now i have bump into a problem is i do not know how to track the XY coordinate of each rectangle after image is scaled up. A better illustration of my problem can be shown in the below figure. Do any experts here have an solution how to calculate the XY coordinates after scaled up/down? Thanks

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EtOb.png)

Comment: Translate the origin to the center of the scaling, multiply everything by the scale factor, and then translate back.

Comment: Hey @amd thanks for your propose method and it's works!